# People skills is correct expression?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I made a campaign video for my app, and I am not sure whether or not "people skills" is the right expression for it; when someone knows what other people generally thinks and feels?

The slogan:

> Do you have good people skills?
>   Guess who match together as couple.
>   If they choose each other you get point.
>   Be the best in people skills.

Answer (score 1):

Yes . It's a correct expression.
 See definition in Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary
"people skills"
  noun   [  plural  ]  : the ability to work with or talk to other people in an effective and friendly way.
 For example:  Good people skills are important in customer service. 
See more examples in the picture :[image]